# JQuery SVG plugin: get space cordinate at page position

Tags: jquery-svg

I've created an SVG canvas inline in HTML, dynamically using keith-wood jquery plugin.

I've used the viewBox attribute in the SVG element to scale the contents of the SVG canvas.

Inside the SVG canvas, I have a rectangle drawn, with a repeated pattern (tiles), each a 1x1 unit.

An 800x800 board:

```
    var svg = $(containerDiv).svg('get');
    svg.configure({viewBox: minX + "" + minY + "" + width + "" + height});
    var pat1 = svg.pattern('pat1', 0, 0, 1, 1, {patternUnits: 'userSpaceOnUse'});
    var rectTile = svg.rect(pat1, 0, 0, 1, 1);
    var rectBoard = svg.rect(0, 0, 800, 800, {fill: 'url(#pat1)'});
```

When the user hovers over one of the elements inside the SVG, I'd like to convert the mouse event's pageX and pageY pixel coordinates to the coordinates of the tile, given the viewBox scaling. So if the user hovers over the first tile, I'd like {x: 0, y: 0} returned, given e.pageX and e.pageY where e is the mousemove jquery event object.

How do I calculate this?

Thanks